# jQuery Tokeninput and the onFreeTaggingAdd callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tokeninput

The jQuery plugin Tokeninput (master branch) (https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput)  has a new feature for adding tags. Unfortunately this feature so far is best documented at Twitter: https://twitter.com/loopj/status/332249287062851585.

I'm trying to figure out how to use the onFreeTaggingAdd, but unfortunately I'm a jQuery and javascript newbie.

In short I would like the callback to take the output from my api and use it in the tokenbox. This way I would be able to modify the tag (lower case etc) and to add an id. I would also be able to replace it by another ID/tag if that's a policy suggested by the api.

Below, please see my code so far. I've tried several options to set item=data and return that value, but so far without success. Any help is appreciated!

```
onFreeTaggingAdd: function (item) {

$.post("../php/add_tagg_02.php", {tag: item, userid: "userid-dummy"} )
.done(function(data, status, xhr) {
alert ("Your suggested new tag " + data.name + " is entered in the database and will be considered for future use.");
console.log( data.name ); //returns the "new" name from the api
console.log( data.id ); //returns the id provided by the api
})
    return item; //returns the "old" name from the user input   
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the library sets a freetag's `ID` to the same as its `name` as a default, the only way to change that would be to edit the `add_freetagging_tokens()` method within the library.

At the point it is called, the token is nothing more than a string, so to change the name, you could simply do this:

```
onFreeTaggingAdd: function (item) {

$.post("../php/add_tagg_02.php", {tag: item, userid: "userid-dummy"} )
.done(function(data, status, xhr) {
alert ("Your suggested new tag " + data.name + " is entered in the database and will be considered for future use.");
console.log( data.name ); //returns the "new" name from the api
console.log( data.id ); //returns the id provided by the api
})
    return data.name; //Sets the tokens Name/ID to be the new name from the api.
},
```

If you did want to also customize the ID, it should be relatively simple to change the method to return an object, instead of a string.

Also be aware that this token obviously won't be searchable for, unless you also update your data source.

Answer (score 2):

You can add and remove token programatically, like from examples:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#demo-input-plugin-methods").tokenInput("http://shell.loopj.com/tokeninput/tvshows.php");
                // Add a token programatically
                $("#plugin-methods-add").click(function () {
                    $("#demo-input-plugin-methods").tokenInput("add", {id: 999, name: "James was here"});
                    return false;
                });
// Remove a token programatically
            $("#plugin-methods-remove").click(function () {
                $("#demo-input-plugin-methods").tokenInput("remove", {name: "James was here"});
                return false;
            });
   });
```

Comment: This is actually working! And the code is quite clean. But I was hoping that it should not be necessary to remove and add like this: ' onFreeTaggingAdd: function (item) {
  $.post("../php/add_tagg_02.php", {tag: item, userid: "userid-dummy"} )
  .done(function(data, status, xhr) {
  alert ("Message");
  $("#tags").tokenInput("remove", {name: "crap"});
  $("#tags").tokenInput("add", {id: data.id, name: data.name});
  })
  return "crap";
 },
'

Comment: I think you are right because you can change tags directly by the script `add_tagg_02.php` if it can handle these operations.